# Fastest way to concatenate slices of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I have a large number of small numpy arrays (groups) of different sizes, and I want to concatenate an arbitrary subset of these groups as fast as possible. The solution I originaly came up with is to store these groups as np.array of np.arrays and then access a subset of groups with list indexing:

```
groups = []
for i in range(100000):
    size = np.random.randint(3) + 1
    groups.append(np.random.randint(1000000, size=size))
groups = np.array(groups)  # dtype=np.object
indices = np.random.randint(len(groups), size=1000)

%%timeit
np.concatenate(groups[indices])
>>> 204 µs ± 395 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

However, this solution is inefficient in terms of memory consumption as groups are small (2 elements on average) and I have to store a numpy array structure for each group, which is almost 100 bytes (too much for me).

To make the solution more efficient I've decided to concatenate all groups and store array boundaries in a separate array

```
data = np.concatenate(groups)
offsets = np.cumsum([0] + [len(group) for group in groups])
# ith group is data[offsets[i]: offsets[i + 1]]
```

But then concatenation is not obvious at all. Something like this:

```
%%timeit
np.concatenate([data[offsets[i]: offsets[i + 1]] for i in indices])
>>> 1.02 ms ± 44.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Works 5 times slower than the original solution. I think this is because of two things. First, iteration over numpy array indices (python wraps c-int into object for each index). Second, python creates numpy structure for each slice/index. I think it's impossible to reduce concatenation time for this case in pure python, so I've decided to come up with a cython solution.

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
ctypedef long long int64

def concatenate(data, offsets, indices):
    cdef int64[::] data_view = data
    cdef int64[::] indices_view = indices
    cdef int64[::] offsets_view = offsets
    
    size = np.sum(offsets[indices + 1]) - np.sum(offsets[indices])
    res = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.int64)
    cdef int64[::] res_view = res
    
    cdef int64 i, l = 0, r
    for i in indices_view:
        r = l + offsets_view[i + 1] - offsets_view[i]
        res_view[l: r] = data_view[offsets_view[i]: offsets_view[i + 1]]
        l = r
    return res

%%timeit
concatenate(data, offsets, indices)
>>> 277 µs ± 89.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

This solution is faster than the previous, but still a little slower than the original. But the biggest problem is that I don't know the data type in advance. I've used int64 in the example, but it could be any number type, e.g. float32. Because of that, I cannot use typed memory views as I did. In theory, I only need to know the size of the type (4/8 bytes) and if I have pointers to the data and result arrays, I can use memcpy or something similar to copy slices. But I don't know how to do it in cython. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my pure numpy-only solution, `adv_concatenate()` function. It gives `15x-47x` times speedup (different on different machines) compared to regular `np.concatenate()`.

**NOTE**: There is also a second faster solution going after the code of first one.

For time measurement for used pip module `timerit`, install it once by `python -m pip install timerit`. For timings two types of machines were used - first machine is Windows-based, it is same for all tests, it is my home laptop, second machine is Linux-based, it is different machine for every test (so different speed between different tests, but same speed inside one run/test), it is machine of [repl.it](https://repl.it/) site that I used to test my code too.

The idea of algorithm was to use numpy's cumulative sum function (`.cumsum()`):

1. We create array of just `1`s, size of array equal to total resulting concatenated data array size. This array will hold indexes of all `data` elements to be fetched to create resulting data array.
2. Inside this array at starting postitions of each block (small sub-array) we change values to in such a way that after running `cumsum()` on whole resulting array this starting values are transformed to starting offsets into `data` array. The remaining values remain `1`s.
3. To this array we apply `.cumsum()`. Now all values will hold correct indexes of data elements to be fetched.
4. We form resulting fetched data array by just indexing `data` with formed above array of indexes.

This algorithm can be potentially boosted even more if we pre-compute some values like `offsets[1:] - offsets[:-1]` or `offsets[:-1] + 1` and use them inside `adv_concatenate()` function.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64350649#main.py)

```
# Needs: python -m pip install numpy timerit
from timerit import Timerit
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
Timerit._default_asciimode = True

groups = []
for i in range(100000):
    size = np.random.randint(3) + 1
    groups.append(np.random.randint(1000000, size = size))
groups = np.array(groups)  # dtype=np.object
indices = np.random.randint(len(groups), size = 1000)

data = np.concatenate(groups)
offsets = np.cumsum([0] + [len(group) for group in groups])

timer = lambda: Timerit(num = 600, verbose = 1)

print('np.concatenate(): ', end = '', flush = True)
tim = timer()
for t in tim:
    with t:
        ref = np.concatenate([data[offsets[i] : offsets[i + 1]] for i in indices])
tref = tim.mean()

def adv_concatenate(data, offsets, indices):
    begs, ends = offsets[indices], offsets[indices + 1]
    lens = ends - begs
    clens = lens.cumsum()
    ix = np.ones((clens[-1],), dtype = offsets.dtype)
    ix[0] = begs[0]
    ix[clens[:-1]] = begs[1:] - ends[:-1] + 1
    ix = ix.cumsum()
    return data[ix]
    
print('adv_concatenate(): ', end = '', flush = True)
tim = timer()
for t in tim:
    with t:
        adv = adv_concatenate(data, offsets, indices)
tadv = tim.mean()
assert np.array_equal(ref, adv) # Check that our solution is correct

print('speedup:', round(tref / tadv, 3))
```

Outputs:

On first machine (Windows):

```
np.concatenate(): Timed best=3.129 ms, mean=3.225 +- 0.1 ms
adv_concatenate(): Timed best=191.137 us, mean=208.012 +- 20.7 us
speedup: 15.504
```

On second machine (Linux):

```
np.concatenate(): Timed best=1.666 ms, mean=2.314 +- 0.4 ms
adv_concatenate(): Timed best=35.596 us, mean=48.680 +- 15.4 us
speedup: 47.532
```

---

**Second solution** is even more faster than first one giving `40x-150x` times speedup (different on different machines) compared to regular `np.concatenate()`. But second solution uses [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) [LLVM](https://llvm.org/)-based compiler, that needs to be installed via `python -m pip install numba`.

Although it uses extra `numba` package still central function `adv_concatenate_indexes_numba()` is very simple, same amount of lines of code as in first solution. Also algorithm is much simpler just, two simple loops.

Current solution works for any data type, because central function just computes resulting indexes, hence doesn't work with `data`'s dtype at all. Also current solution can be boosted by `10%-90%` more if instead of computing indexes numba function will compute straight resulting data array, but this is only possible for quite simple data types that are supported by numba, including all number types. [Here is the code](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64350649var3) (or [here](https://tio.run/##rVVNb9swDL3rVxDoIRLqegk6FIOBAgN27y69GUag2HKjzJY0Se6a/fmM@nCcflwG1EBiiSL53hMZxhz9Xqvb0@kKHoToXAUmWuBmBCMNSOU8HwZQ02iO4XvHwctRWOlJb/U4b0CORlsPj/ksb1MYd6BMkaKJMqXlqtNj6RCQrhnJMeW2Ez2fBr/lrpVy1J2Ae3i0kyDkyerJONzWDem1BYnEANM8CbpZh4dVBPBx8m8IWjDCSypPbxlcwyb6pFwlN0aojr53TQnXxZwsvAro/NHk1Oh095WxhRTauLX8SJOFAVwl/3s80buDaPFCMHkr3IfkBqHm0DPqJlJ4h0pIxz1Pllarlnuh8DOHE933TvgM006jm0ZarxsUX59RGIQrjMtwjSm0@RAsVhdNAx93Ha/m8lIsJVrvAsVnYXfaRcoYYGwQtHrDjlWwKgCvG71WuOqHye1zcVkAwXWEoiyW1wdeaEhF/SP9Hnxah8eK/v0F1OFe6iy/lg1UcN6E0jcNnBsn16JB6JQLocpRcIXw5Hts01IdUOZKfqurhsbvAi5fDFW0vN2LswpsXuDd8/aC1DamooFZMbMpZvTcsR7LgjnWcfOmtbNnGVqCLfrlCwbkM1R6tsdU1/eL7pcoHG4uLIt3XBiNhEKBsZB4oWI0/khpSFSwpSGCgDJu2CfQDNGHJfqCW/GW@kW2WPga@TaZUH1oXh3iURC/eWUkqV/8ZBEubsh/1Qh/yD9VK8BYcdPq0chBwEMcY7nRP872uf2OGOj/X7yJT0EXjc2dE2Ei51m1Fb8nPlDs/yKkDkp/7EX7C/yee9CTBaeHyUv8K5AOWm1tmGKzbGdwdk@mQm04PXCMxh/SFwiwBdzicDyd/gE)) for this improved solution which achieves up to `250x` speedup! Timings for this improved version on second machine (Linux):

```
np.concatenate(): Timed best=1.640 ms, mean=3.403 +- 1.9 ms
adv_concatenate_numba(): Timed best=12.669 us, mean=17.235 +- 6.9 us
speedup: 197.46
```

More generic (only-indexes-computing) solution's code is going next:

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64350649var2#main.py)

```
# Needs: python -m pip install numpy numba timerit
from timerit import Timerit
import numpy as np, numba
np.random.seed(0)
Timerit._default_asciimode = True

groups = []
for i in range(100000):
    size = np.random.randint(3) + 1
    groups.append(np.random.randint(1000000, size = size, dtype = np.int64))
groups = np.array(groups)  # dtype=np.object
indices = np.random.randint(len(groups), size = 1000, dtype = np.int64)

data = np.concatenate(groups)
offsets = np.cumsum([0] + [len(group) for group in groups], dtype = np.int64)

timer = lambda: Timerit(num = 600, verbose = 1)

print('np.concatenate(): ', end = '', flush = True)
tim = timer()
for t in tim:
    with t:
        ref = np.concatenate([data[offsets[i] : offsets[i + 1]] for i in indices])
tref = tim.mean()

@numba.njit('i8[:](i8[:], i8[:])', cache = True)
def adv_concatenate_indexes_numba(offsets, indices):
    tlen = 0
    for i in range(indices.size):
        ix = indices[i]
        tlen += offsets[ix + 1] - offsets[ix]
        
    pos, r = 0, np.empty((tlen,), dtype = offsets.dtype)
    for i in range(indices.size):
        ix = indices[i]
        for j in range(offsets[ix], offsets[ix + 1]):
            r[pos] = j
            pos += 1
            
    return r
    
def adv_concatenate2(data, offsets, indices):
    return data[adv_concatenate_indexes_numba(offsets, indices)]
    
adv_concatenate2(data, offsets, indices) # Once pre-compile Numba
print('adv_concatenate2(): ', end = '', flush = True)
tim = timer()
for t in tim:
    with t:
        adv = adv_concatenate2(data, offsets, indices)
tadv = tim.mean()
assert np.array_equal(ref, adv) # Check that our solution is correct

print('speedup:', round(tref / tadv, 3))
```

Output:

On first machine (Windows):

```
np.concatenate(): Timed best=3.201 ms, mean=3.356 +- 0.1 ms
adv_concatenate2(): Timed best=79.681 us, mean=82.991 +- 6.7 us
speedup: 40.442
```

On second machine (Linux):

```
np.concatenate(): Timed best=1.541 ms, mean=2.220 +- 0.7 ms
adv_concatenate2(): Timed best=12.012 us, mean=14.830 +- 4.8 us
speedup: 149.716
```

Inspired by Cython code of @pavelgramovich [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64371864/941531) I've also decided to implement my simplified version with loop (func `concatenate1()`) instead of `memcpy()` version (func `concatenate0()`), simplified version appeared to be `1.5-2x` faster than memcpy version for current test data. Full code comparing both versions down below:

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64350649var4#main.py)

```
# Needs: python -m pip install numpy timerit cython setuptools
from timerit import Timerit
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
Timerit._default_asciimode = True

groups = []
for i in range(100000):
    size = np.random.randint(3) + 1
    groups.append(np.random.randint(1000000, size = size, dtype = np.int64))
groups = np.array(groups)  # dtype=np.object
indices = np.random.randint(len(groups), size = 1000, dtype = np.int64)

data = np.concatenate(groups)
offsets = np.cumsum([0] + [len(group) for group in groups], dtype = np.int64)

timer = lambda: Timerit(num = 600, verbose = 1)

def compile_cy_cats():
    src = """
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from libc.string cimport memcpy 

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def concatenate0(np.ndarray data, np.ndarray offsets, np.ndarray indices):
    data = np.ascontiguousarray(data)
    start_offsets = np.ascontiguousarray(offsets[indices], dtype=np.int64)
    end_offsets = np.ascontiguousarray(offsets[indices + 1], dtype=np.int64)
    cdef np.int64_t[::1] coffsets = start_offsets
    cdef np.int64_t[::1] csizes = end_offsets - start_offsets
    
    cdef np.int64_t i, total_size = 0
    for i in range(csizes.shape[0]):
        total_size += csizes[i]
    res = np.empty(total_size, dtype=data.dtype)

    cdef np.ndarray cdata = data
    cdef np.ndarray cres = res
    
    cdef np.int64_t itemsize = data.itemsize
    cdef np.int64_t res_offset = 0
    for i in range(csizes.shape[0]):
        memcpy(cres.data + res_offset * itemsize, 
               cdata.data + coffsets[i] * itemsize, 
               csizes[i] * itemsize)
        res_offset += csizes[i]
    
    return res

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def concatenate1(np.int64_t[:] data, np.int64_t[:] offsets, np.int64_t[:] indices):
    cdef np.int64_t tlen = 0, pos = 0, ix = 0, ixs = indices.size, i = 0, j = 0
    
    for i in range(ixs):
        ix = indices[i]
        tlen += offsets[ix + 1] - offsets[ix]
        
    r = np.empty(tlen, dtype = np.int64)
    cdef np.int64_t[:] cr = r, cdata = data

    for i in range(ixs):
        ix = indices[i]
        for j in range(offsets[ix], offsets[ix + 1]):
            cr[pos] = cdata[j]
            pos += 1
    
    return r
    """
    
    srcb = src.encode('utf-8')
    
    import hashlib, os, glob, importlib
    srch = hashlib.sha256(srcb).hexdigest().upper()[:8]

    if len(glob.glob(f'cy{srch}*')) == 0:
        with open(f'cys{srch}.pyx', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(srcb)

        import sys
        from setuptools import setup, Extension
        from Cython.Build import cythonize
        import numpy as np

        sys.argv += ['build_ext', '--inplace']
        setup(
            ext_modules = cythonize(
                Extension(f'cy{srch}', [f'cys{srch}.pyx']), language_level = 3, annotate = True,
            ),
            include_dirs = [np.get_include()],
        )
        del sys.argv[-2:]

    print('Cython module:', f'cy{srch}')
    return importlib.import_module(f'cy{srch}')

cy_cats = compile_cy_cats()
concatenate0, concatenate1 = cy_cats.concatenate0, cy_cats.concatenate1

print('np.concatenate(): ', end = '', flush = True)
tim = timer()
for t in tim:
    with t:
        ref = np.concatenate([data[offsets[i] : offsets[i + 1]] for i in indices])
tref = tim.mean()

concatenate0(data, offsets, indices) # Maybe pre-heat
print('cy_concatenate0(): ', end = '', flush = True)
tim = timer()
for t in tim:
    with t:
        adv0 = concatenate0(data, offsets, indices)
tadv0 = tim.mean()
assert np.array_equal(ref, adv0) # Check that our solution is correct

print('speedup:', round(tref / tadv0, 3))

concatenate1(data, offsets, indices) # Maybe pre-heat
print('cy_concatenate1(): ', end = '', flush = True)
tim = timer()
for t in tim:
    with t:
        adv1 = concatenate1(data, offsets, indices)
tadv1 = tim.mean()
assert np.array_equal(ref, adv1) # Check that our solution is correct

print('speedup:', round(tref / tadv1, 3))
```

Output:

First machine (Windows):

```
Cython module: cy0BEBA0C8
np.concatenate(): Timed best=3.184 ms, mean=3.263 +- 0.1 ms
cy_concatenate0(): Timed best=119.767 us, mean=128.688 +- 10.7 us
speedup: 25.354
cy_concatenate1(): Timed best=86.525 us, mean=93.699 +- 20.5 us
speedup: 34.821
```

Second machine (Linux):

```
Cython module: cy0BEBA0C8
np.concatenate(): Timed best=1.630 ms, mean=2.215 +- 0.5 ms
cy_concatenate0(): Timed best=21.839 us, mean=28.930 +- 8.4 us
speedup: 76.578
cy_concatenate1(): Timed best=11.447 us, mean=15.263 +- 5.1 us
speedup: 145.151
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I didn't expect there might be a pure python solution that actually works fast. The key was to think in terms of indices to `data` array, and that was not obvious to me. It seemed like such an approach could not work fast as you have to calculate indices array first, which is as big as the resulting array. Apparently I was wrong. Numba solution works even faster than what I did in cython. Any idea why that might be? Maybe difference in compilers or compile arguments?

Comment: I've checked what will happen if average group size will be 50 instead of 2. Solutions that explicitly compute indices to `data` start to work much slower (still better than the naive approach). I think that is because information about block structure is lost and numpy just copies elements one by one in a loop instead of copying whole blocks with memcpy.

Comment: On the other hand, if you compute indices to `data` you don't have to make `data` array contiguous, which you have to do if you want to use memcpy.

Comment: @pavelgramovich Numba in `nopython` mode (which is used in `.njit()` decorator) forces to have no Python objects at all, no interaction with python or python API, just pure C++. But Cython I think has no such forcing behavior, hence you have to cythonize with `annotate = True` flag and see maybe there's some interaction with Python which has yellow lines in annotated HTML.

Comment: @pavelgramovich Also I think using `memcpy()` especially for quite small groups can be a big overhead and slow, because `memcpy()` function is not just pure machine instruction for copying, it has some preparation overhead, checkin alignment, etc, also just calling function too is overhead (it might be not inlined by C/C++). Probably memcpy is good enough for block of at least a hundred bytes or more. Below just a regular loop should copy better.

Comment: @pavelgramovich BTW, Notice that I mentioned two versions of numba code in my answer. One is computing just pure indexes and returns them, this version is more generic and doesn't work or need to know about data type, but slower (almost 1.2x-2x times slower). And another optimized version ([located here](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64350649var3)) instead of creating indexes just copies data itself, but needs to know about data type, it is significantly faster, so this faster version should be always used if Numba code can compile with that data type.

Comment: @pavelgramovich BTW, you should noticed that I provided exact function signature in Numba `njit` decorator e.g. `'i8[:](i8[:], i8[:])'`, so this signature forces Numba to compile function just once for given fixed input types. But you may remove this signature string, then Numba will re-compile code each time it meets a new signature, but this allows any different data types to be passed in. Also there should be syntax for providing multiple signatures. Providing fixed signature is sometimes faster because it remove necessity for Numba checking input args types each time on call.

Comment: @pavelgramovich BTW Numba is quite mature project, hence it should support all Numpy data types already (dtype of arrays). Hence you can probably always use without problems faster version which copies data instead of creating just indexes. I mean faster version [that is here](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64350649var3). In any case you should use this faster version always whenever Numba successfully managed to compile it without complains or errors.Also you probably want to remove fixed signature from `njit` decorator so that any data type is supported,but no signature can be slower

Comment: @pavelgramovich I've just implemented my own Cython version, simplified one with just regular copy-loop instead of `memcpy()`. [Here is the code](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64350649var4#main.py), it compares both versions (your and mine) against current test data of regular `np.concatenate()`. It appeared to be that regular copy-loop version is `1.5x-2x` times faster than `memcpy()` version.

Comment: @pavelgramovich Although this no-memcpy version is for int64 data only, still it can be modified to support any Cython-supported numpy data type. Also in case of some rare unsupported data types we can use technique mentioned earlier - to compute just indexes of concatenated array and then do code `result = data[indexes]` in Python code outside Cython module, this will lose `15%-30%` of speed but will be suitable for any possible data type.

Comment: @pavelgramovich BTW, Regarding Numba - it is not only [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) compiler but also [AOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation), which means that Numba code can be pre-compiled once same like Cython code into binary `.pyd/.so` module and used later without any dependencies, without needing to install pip `numba` module. [Here is example](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/pycc.html) of Numba ahead of time compilation.

Comment: @pavelgramovich Main disadvantage of Numba is that it is not that tweakable and professional as Cython is. Numba is like a very easy and quick way to optimize your short and simple algorithms. Numba can compile function only in two modes - pure-Python and no-Python, first will have a lot of interaction with Python API, same like using no `cdefs` inside Cython, second mode is no-Python similar to using all possible optimizations and lots of `cdefs` inside Cython, so Numba has no intermediate possibility to mix these two modes, unlike Cython which has.So Numba is just simple but not professional

Comment: @pavelgramovich BTW, I've just noticed that `timerit` is very inaccurate for very fast code time-measuring. E.g. for empty code `pass` it reports running time of `3-5mcsec` (`usec`). And my numba code is around `10-12 us`, so it is probably measured very inaccurately. If we want more accurate measurements then either measured code should be repeated several times inside measuring block or test data should be bigger, e.g. not 1000 indices but 100000. Numba/Cython code may appear even much faster but if we measure timings accurately.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to concatenate slices of an array of arbitrary dtype with cython. There is a c-counterpart of a python numpy.ndarray class. It contains a pointer `data` to the beginning of an underlying c-array and attribute `itemsize`, which stores the size of a single element in bytes. With that, it becomes possible to concatenate slices using `memcpy`.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from libc.string cimport memcpy 

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def concatenate(np.ndarray data, np.ndarray offsets, np.ndarray indices):
    data = np.ascontiguousarray(data)
    start_offsets = np.ascontiguousarray(offsets[indices], dtype=np.int64)
    end_offsets = np.ascontiguousarray(offsets[indices + 1], dtype=np.int64)
    cdef np.int64_t[::1] coffsets = start_offsets
    cdef np.int64_t[::1] csizes = end_offsets - start_offsets
    
    cdef np.int64_t i, total_size = 0
    for i in range(csizes.shape[0]):
        total_size += csizes[i]
    res = np.empty(total_size, dtype=data.dtype)

    cdef np.ndarray cdata = data
    cdef np.ndarray cres = res
    
    cdef np.int64_t itemsize = data.itemsize
    cdef np.int64_t res_offset = 0
    for i in range(csizes.shape[0]):
        memcpy(cres.data + res_offset * itemsize, 
               cdata.data + coffsets[i] * itemsize, 
               csizes[i] * itemsize)
        res_offset += csizes[i]
    
    return res

%%timeit
concatenate(data, offsets, indices)
>>> 21.1 µs ± 24.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Always wanted to learn Cython! :) `C++` and `Python` are two my favorite languages, but still I didn't learn good enough way to join both of them.

Comment: BTW, If you can afford losing not to much (`10%-30%`) of efficiency then you can just compute resulting indexes of elements of concatenated arrays in your Cython code. Then you will not need to know anything about underlying data type, you will just work with offsets and indexes hence only int32/int64 numbers. And a pure Python/Numpy outer function will just do `result = data[cython_concatenated_indexes(offsets, indices)]`.

Comment: I've just implemented my own Cython version, simplified one with just regular copy-loop instead of `memcpy()`. [Here is the code](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64350649var4#main.py), it compares both versions (your and mine) against current test data of regular `np.concatenate()`. It appeared to be that regular copy-loop version is `1.5x-2x` times faster than `memcpy()` version.